# Copy/Paste CheckBoxes If True In PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

I am trying to copy all true or checked boxes on all slides and paste them onto one slide within my presentation. I can't seem to figure it out. Below is the code that I am using. Any help is appreciated.

```
`Sub ckbxCopy()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For i = 1 To 4
        shp = ActivePresentation.Slides("CheckBox" & CStr(i))
    If Err.Number = 0 Then  ' shape exists
        If shp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
            shp.Copy
            ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes.Paste
        End If
    End If
    Next i
Next sld
End Sub`
```

Comment: What happens (or doesn't happen) when you run your code, and how is that different from what you want/expect?  If you comment out `On Error Resume Next` you may see you're missing Set here:  `Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides("CheckBox" & CStr(i))`

Comment: I commented out the On Error Resume Next statement and get 12 copies of CheckBox2 only on slide 3.  There are only 3 slides in my test presentation; slide 1 has 3 checkboxes with checkbox2 checked, slide 2 has 3 checkboxes with checkbox1 and checkbox3 checked and slide 3 is blank. What I would like to get is only those checkboxes that are checked to be copied to slide 3 . I will have to fiddle with the formatting later, but I would like to get this piece done first.

Comment: You need to exclude slide 3 from the loop which goes over all the slides...

Comment: I removed slide 3 from the loop but it is not pasting properly.  It is pasting only 1 instance of "ActivePresentation.Slides("CheckBox" & CStr(i)).  I am trying to get the 3 checked items onto slide 3.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```vb
Sub ckbxCopy()

    Dim shp As Shape, pres As Presentation
    Dim sld As Slide, sldDest As Slide
    Dim i As Integer, t As Long
    
    Set pres = ActivePresentation
    Set sldDest = pres.Slides(3)    'where shapes are to be pasted
    
    sldDest.Shapes.Range.Delete 'remove existing shapes
    t = 20
    For Each sld In pres.Slides
        If sld.SlideIndex <> sldDest.SlideIndex Then
            For i = 1 To 4
                Set shp = Nothing
                Set shp = SlideShape(sld, "CheckBox" & CStr(i))
                If Not shp Is Nothing Then
                    If shp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
                        shp.Copy
                        pres.Slides(3).Shapes.Paste.Top = t 'paste and position
                        t = t + 20
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next sld
End Sub

'Return a named shape from a slide (or Nothing if the shape doesn't exist)
Function SlideShape(sld As Slide, shapeName As String) As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SlideShape = sld.Shapes(shapeName)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! This turned out to be more involved that I initially thought.